# Unable to execute PHP code on Windows 10 through xampp

Tags: windows-10, php, xampp

I'm new to php and i'm using xampp on windows 10....when i save the file in .php format and open it in the chrome browser....the browser returns the php code instead of execution!! please help!
[pic in the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIwOD.png)

Comment: read the instructions about "Testing XAMPP"

Answer (score 2):

Xampp is a software package that allows you to host a webserver on your computer.

In order to work with this, you will need to start the webserver, and point your browser to your ip address followed by the path to the script.

Just doubleclicking the php file will indeed open the file as if it were a html file and show you the code rather than executing it.

When you start a Xampp webserver, it should launch a webbrowser with the main page, making it easier to navigate to the new php file.

If you need more help on how to use Xampp, I suggest to access the help files either online or those that came with the Xampp package.

Comment: I believe the default port xampp runs on is port 80. I believe OP should be able to go to http://localhost/1.php to view the executed code.